# SQL - listing members on enrolled classes

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to figure out why this isn't working. I am trying to select each member's names and the classes that each member is enrolled on together with the class trainers name.

This is what I have at the minute:

```
SELECT 
    firstName, lastName, className, trainerName 
FROM 
    member, _class, trainer, enrolment 
WHERE 
    enrolment.memberID = member.memberID 
    AND enrolment.classID = _class.classID;
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated as I am still learning SQL.

Extra info:

- `enrolment` table has columns entrolmentID, memberID and classID
- `trainer` table has columns trainerID and trainerName
- `member` table has memberID, firstName, lastName, age, trainerID
- `class` table has classID, className, _day and trainerID

Comment: Please use `JOIN`s instead of multiple tables in `FROM` clause

Comment: you have to make any additionnal table linked with Left Join

Comment: include member.trainerID=trainer.trainerID

Comment: Does `member` , `class` and `enrolment` represent three different tables? if they do you should consider using a `JOIN`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valid syntax for a `JOIN` statement is:

```
SELECT FIELD1
    ,...FIELDN
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.FIELDX = T2.FIELDY
```

So in your case, use:

```
SELECT firstName
    ,lastName
    ,className
    ,trainerName
FROM member
INNER JOIN enrolment ON enrolment.memberID = member.memberID
INNER JOIN _class ON enrolment.classID = _class.classID
INNER JOIN trainer ON trainer.trainerID = member.trainerID
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try it? Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, classname, trainerName
FROM member
INNER JOIN enrollment 
ON enrolment.memberID = member.memberID
INNER JOIN _class
ON enrollment.classID = class.classID
INNER JOIN trainer
ON trainer.trainerID = member.trainerID
```